# How to push the contents of a datatable to a powerpoint slide using C# 2.0

Tags: c#-2.0

I have a powerpoint template where the slide should get populated with the contents of a C# datatable. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing here to confirm that Microsoft.Office.Interop library can be used to perform operations read/write operations on Powerpoint and Excel using C# and it is supported on 2.0 framework and higher versions whereas OpenXML package can be used only with versions 3.5 and higher.

Another Third part package Aspose is also an additional option.

Please make use of this one if helpful.

Thanks.